# Enthought - Canopy Express Installation Problems (Windows 7 x64)

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

I am having difficulties installing the Enthought Canopy Express program. I have tried both the x64 and x86 versions.

My login is normal alpha characters only (as goes for the hostname). I have also tried installing under the local admin account (my account has admin rights as well). The installer runs through it's normal motions. I have tried installing for my account only, and for all users.

The environment setup is where it hangs up (I have tried clearing the PATH variable setup as it had previous Enthought info, but that did not help). It will, the first time, ask where to set the Canopy environment directory and initialize the setup. I never get the prompt about Canopy becoming the default Python environment. The progress bar runs shows that it finishes, but nothing ever launches. I can't see anything attempting to run in the taskbar.

When I try to re-launch Canopy, it tells me that it is cleaning up an invalid install and runs the "Setting up Canopy environment" progress bar again. I have tried removing all traces of Python, Canopy, and Enthought from my computer, restarting, and installing with similar results.

I have included the log file.

```
INFO|2013-10-19 13:12:08,861|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:12:08,878|Acquired bootstrap lock.
INFO|2013-10-19 13:12:08,878|Bootstrap settings: {'_lock': <canopy.app.bootstrap.BootstrapLock object at 0x00000000043502B0>,
 '_logging_setup': True,
 '_options': Namespace(batch_mode=False, common_install=False, default=False, factory_reset=False, func=None, install_dir='', no_gui_setup=False, profile='', recovery_mode=False),
 '_proc_manager': <canopy.app.running_process_manager.RunningProcessManager object at 0x000000000401DB38>,
 '_use_running_python_for_venv_ops': False,
 'app_name': 'Canopy',
 'app_root': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App',
 'application_home': 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Enthought\\Canopy',
 'batch_mode': False,
 'bits': '64bit',
 'common_layer1': '',
 'common_layer2': '',
 'company_name': 'Enthought',
 'esky_app': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\Canopy.exe',
 'esky_appdir': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64',
 'has_venv': True,
 'is_esky_app': True,
 'layer0_location': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64',
 'layer1_location': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System',
 'layer2_location': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User',
 'no_gui': False,
 'orig_app_name': 'Canopy',
 'product_name': 'Canopy',
 'profile': '',
 'python_for_installer': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l0': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l1': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l2': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'read_only': False,
 'scripts_dir': 'Scripts',
 'user_data': 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Canopy'}
INFO|2013-10-19 13:12:08,878|Creating venv in layer1: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System
INFO|2013-10-19 13:12:09,282|Doing platform specific install.
INFO|2013-10-19 13:12:09,315|Creating venv in layer2: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User
INFO|2013-10-19 13:12:09,704|Doing platform specific install.
INFO|2013-10-19 13:12:09,736|Running layer installation as: ['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\\Lib\\site-packages\\canopy\\app\\layer_installer.pyc', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', '--home', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Enthought\\Canopy', '--layer1', '--layer2']
ERROR|2013-10-19 13:12:58,157|None
ERROR|2013-10-19 13:12:58,157|Error running layer installer.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1107, in post_venv_install
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 58, in check_call
  File "C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\\Lib\\site-packages\\canopy\\app\\layer_installer.pyc', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', '--home', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Enthought\\Canopy', '--layer1', '--layer2']' returned non-zero exit status 1
INFO|2013-10-19 13:17:02,766|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:17:02,891|Bootstrap already locked by dead process.
INFO|2013-10-19 13:17:02,891|Process that locked layers is dead with info {'status': 'install', 'layer': 2}
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:17:02,891|Acquired bootstrap lock.
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:17:02,891|Wipe out C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:17:03,951|---------- starting GUI event loop ----------
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:17:04,358|Wipe out C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:17:04,358|---------- starting GUI event loop ----------
INFO|2013-10-19 13:17:07,088|Bootstrap settings: {'_lock': <canopy.app.bootstrap.BootstrapLock object at 0x0000000002FE7A90>,
 '_logging_setup': True,
 '_options': Namespace(batch_mode=False, common_install=False, default=False, factory_reset=False, func=None, install_dir='', no_gui_setup=False, profile='', recovery_mode=False),
 '_proc_manager': <canopy.app.running_process_manager.RunningProcessManager object at 0x0000000003002A20>,
 '_use_running_python_for_venv_ops': False,
 'app_name': 'Canopy',
 'app_root': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App',
 'application_home': 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Enthought\\Canopy',
 'batch_mode': False,
 'bits': '64bit',
 'common_layer1': '',
 'common_layer2': '',
 'company_name': 'Enthought',
 'esky_app': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\Canopy.exe',
 'esky_appdir': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64',
 'has_venv': True,
 'is_esky_app': True,
 'layer0_location': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64',
 'layer1_location': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System',
 'layer2_location': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User',
 'no_gui': False,
 'orig_app_name': 'Canopy',
 'product_name': 'Canopy',
 'profile': '',
 'python_for_installer': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l0': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l1': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l2': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'read_only': False,
 'scripts_dir': 'Scripts',
 'user_data': 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Canopy'}
INFO|2013-10-19 13:17:07,088|Creating venv in layer1: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System
INFO|2013-10-19 13:17:07,509|Doing platform specific install.
INFO|2013-10-19 13:17:07,525|Creating venv in layer2: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User
INFO|2013-10-19 13:17:07,976|Doing platform specific install.
INFO|2013-10-19 13:17:08,023|Running layer installation as: ['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\\Lib\\site-packages\\canopy\\app\\layer_installer.pyc', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', '--home', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Enthought\\Canopy', '--layer1', '--layer2']
ERROR|2013-10-19 13:17:55,369|None
ERROR|2013-10-19 13:17:55,369|Error running layer installer.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1107, in post_venv_install
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 58, in check_call
  File "C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\\Lib\\site-packages\\canopy\\app\\layer_installer.pyc', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', '--home', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Enthought\\Canopy', '--layer1', '--layer2']' returned non-zero exit status 1
INFO|2013-10-19 13:22:49,038|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:22:49,163|Bootstrap already locked by dead process.
INFO|2013-10-19 13:22:49,163|Process that locked layers is dead with info {'status': 'install', 'layer': 2}
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:22:49,163|Acquired bootstrap lock.
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:22:49,163|Wipe out C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:22:49,786|---------- starting GUI event loop ----------
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:22:50,191|Wipe out C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:22:50,191|---------- starting GUI event loop ----------
INFO|2013-10-19 13:22:52,859|Bootstrap settings: {'_lock': <canopy.app.bootstrap.BootstrapLock object at 0x000000000300CA90>,
 '_logging_setup': True,
 '_options': Namespace(batch_mode=False, common_install=False, default=False, factory_reset=False, func=None, install_dir='', no_gui_setup=False, profile='', recovery_mode=False),
 '_proc_manager': <canopy.app.running_process_manager.RunningProcessManager object at 0x0000000003027A20>,
 '_use_running_python_for_venv_ops': False,
 'app_name': 'Canopy',
 'app_root': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App',
 'application_home': 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Enthought\\Canopy',
 'batch_mode': False,
 'bits': '64bit',
 'common_layer1': '',
 'common_layer2': '',
 'company_name': 'Enthought',
 'esky_app': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\Canopy.exe',
 'esky_appdir': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64',
 'has_venv': True,
 'is_esky_app': True,
 'layer0_location': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64',
 'layer1_location': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System',
 'layer2_location': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User',
 'no_gui': False,
 'orig_app_name': 'Canopy',
 'product_name': 'Canopy',
 'profile': '',
 'python_for_installer': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l0': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l1': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l2': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'read_only': False,
 'scripts_dir': 'Scripts',
 'user_data': 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Canopy'}
INFO|2013-10-19 13:22:52,875|Creating venv in layer1: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System
INFO|2013-10-19 13:22:53,280|Doing platform specific install.
INFO|2013-10-19 13:22:53,296|Creating venv in layer2: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User
INFO|2013-10-19 13:22:53,717|Doing platform specific install.
INFO|2013-10-19 13:22:54,904|Running layer installation as: ['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\\Lib\\site-packages\\canopy\\app\\layer_installer.pyc', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', '--home', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Enthought\\Canopy', '--layer1', '--layer2']
ERROR|2013-10-19 13:23:41,391|None
ERROR|2013-10-19 13:23:41,391|Error running layer installer.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1107, in post_venv_install
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 58, in check_call
  File "C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\\Lib\\site-packages\\canopy\\app\\layer_installer.pyc', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', '--home', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Enthought\\Canopy', '--layer1', '--layer2']' returned non-zero exit status 1
INFO|2013-10-19 13:45:39,947|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:45:40,072|Bootstrap already locked by dead process.
INFO|2013-10-19 13:45:40,072|Process that locked layers is dead with info {'status': 'install', 'layer': 2}
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:45:40,072|Acquired bootstrap lock.
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:45:40,072|Wipe out C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:45:40,696|---------- starting GUI event loop ----------
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:45:41,101|Wipe out C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User
DEBUG|2013-10-19 13:45:41,101|---------- starting GUI event loop ----------
INFO|2013-10-19 13:45:43,815|Bootstrap settings: {'_lock': <canopy.app.bootstrap.BootstrapLock object at 0x000000000304CA90>,
 '_logging_setup': True,
 '_options': Namespace(batch_mode=False, common_install=False, default=False, factory_reset=False, func=None, install_dir='', no_gui_setup=False, profile='', recovery_mode=False),
 '_proc_manager': <canopy.app.running_process_manager.RunningProcessManager object at 0x0000000003067A20>,
 '_use_running_python_for_venv_ops': False,
 'app_name': 'Canopy',
 'app_root': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App',
 'application_home': 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Enthought\\Canopy',
 'batch_mode': False,
 'bits': '64bit',
 'common_layer1': '',
 'common_layer2': '',
 'company_name': 'Enthought',
 'esky_app': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\Canopy.exe',
 'esky_appdir': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64',
 'has_venv': True,
 'is_esky_app': True,
 'layer0_location': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64',
 'layer1_location': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System',
 'layer2_location': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User',
 'no_gui': False,
 'orig_app_name': 'Canopy',
 'product_name': 'Canopy',
 'profile': '',
 'python_for_installer': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l0': 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l1': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l2': u'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'read_only': False,
 'scripts_dir': 'Scripts',
 'user_data': 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Canopy'}
INFO|2013-10-19 13:45:43,832|Creating venv in layer1: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System
INFO|2013-10-19 13:45:44,237|Doing platform specific install.
INFO|2013-10-19 13:45:44,269|Creating venv in layer2: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User
INFO|2013-10-19 13:45:44,658|Doing platform specific install.
INFO|2013-10-19 13:45:44,706|Running layer installation as: ['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\\Lib\\site-packages\\canopy\\app\\layer_installer.pyc', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', '--home', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Enthought\\Canopy', '--layer1', '--layer2']
ERROR|2013-10-19 13:46:32,252|None
ERROR|2013-10-19 13:46:32,252|Error running layer installer.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1107, in post_venv_install
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 58, in check_call
  File "C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\\Lib\\site-packages\\canopy\\app\\layer_installer.pyc', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', '--home', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Enthought\\Canopy', '--layer1', '--layer2']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

I deleted the directories recommended by Jonathan:

...\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System\
...\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\
...\AppData\Roaming\Enthought\Canopy\

Then I ran Canopy **as Administrator** and the environment was successfully created.  I've often found I need to resort to running software as Admin under Windows 7.

System: Canopy 64-bit on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Cheers
Andy

Answer (score 0):

You've done good research, sorry that it did not suffice. Clearly the error reporting needs improvement. Do you have lots of free disk space (IIRC close to 400 MB) on your C: drive even after the initial install step (i.e. before initial Canopy startup)? During first startup, the Express package eggs are unpacked into the Canopy User Python environment; this takes up much disk space, especially scipy, sympy, matplotlib, pandas, numpy.

If space *is* the problem, and it's not feasible to free up enough space on C:, then you could specify your environment path on a drive with more free space available.

To try again, you should not need to re-install; it should suffice to delete the following directories, and restart Canopy:

```
...\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System\
...\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\
...\AppData\Roaming\Enthought\Canopy\
```

Comment: I have around 90 GB's free, even before the initial install. I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I have two storage devices - a SSD with my OS installed on it, and a secondary HDD. I tried installing it on the HDD (it has much more free space), but seemed to do the same.