# Python Enthought Canopy Refuses to work

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

I installed Canopy and after a continuous loop it crashed. Brought up this bug report. I have uninstalled, restarted and reinstalled but to no avail. Here is my log:  I need this to work for a programme course:  Please help. Here is log:

```
NFO|2013-10-31 11:20:36,380|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
DEBUG|2013-10-31 11:20:36,380|Acquired bootstrap lock.
INFO|2013-10-31 11:20:36,395|Bootstrap settings: {'_lock': <canopy.app.bootstrap.BootstrapLock object at 0x012E5910>,
 '_logging_setup': True,
 '_options': Namespace(batch_mode=False, common_install=False, default=False, factory_reset=False, func=None, install_dir='', no_gui_setup=False, profile='', recovery_mode=False),
 '_proc_manager': <canopy.app.running_process_manager.RunningProcessManager object at 0x012E58B0>,
 '_use_running_python_for_venv_ops': False,
 'app_name': 'Canopy',
 'app_root': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App',
 'application_home': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy',
 'batch_mode': False,
 'bits': '32bit',
 'common_layer1': '',
 'common_layer2': '',
 'company_name': 'Enthought',
 'esky_app': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App\\Canopy.exe',
 'esky_appdir': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86',
 'has_venv': True,
 'is_esky_app': True,
 'layer0_location': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86',
 'layer1_location': u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\System',
 'layer2_location': u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\User',
 'no_gui': False,
 'orig_app_name': 'Canopy',
 'product_name': 'Canopy',
 'profile': '',
 'python_for_installer': u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l0': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l1': u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l2': u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\User\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'read_only': False,
 'scripts_dir': 'Scripts',
 'user_data': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Canopy'}
INFO|2013-10-31 11:20:36,395|Running app with args: [u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', '-c', 'from canopy.app.main import main; main()']
INFO|2013-10-31 11:20:36,411|Supervising crashes with: ['C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86\\Lib\\site-packages\\canopy\\app\\supervisor.pyc', '--pid', '1456', '--home', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy', '--app', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App\\Canopy.exe']
INFO|2013-10-31 12:11:23,171|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
DEBUG|2013-10-31 12:11:23,217|Acquired bootstrap lock.
INFO|2013-10-31 12:11:23,296|Bootstrap settings: {'_lock': <canopy.app.bootstrap.BootstrapLock object at 0x012E5910>,
 '_logging_setup': True,
 '_options': Namespace(batch_mode=False, common_install=False, default=False, factory_reset=False, func=None, install_dir='', no_gui_setup=False, profile='', recovery_mode=False),
 '_proc_manager': <canopy.app.running_process_manager.RunningProcessManager object at 0x012E58B0>,
 '_use_running_python_for_venv_ops': False,
 'app_name': 'Canopy',
 'app_root': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App',
 'application_home': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy',
 'batch_mode': False,
 'bits': '32bit',
 'common_layer1': '',
 'common_layer2': '',
 'company_name': 'Enthought',
 'esky_app': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App\\Canopy.exe',
 'esky_appdir': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86',
 'has_venv': True,
 'is_esky_app': True,
 'layer0_location': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86',
 'layer1_location': u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\System',
 'layer2_location': u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\User',
 'no_gui': False,
 'orig_app_name': 'Canopy',
 'product_name': 'Canopy',
 'profile': '',
 'python_for_installer': u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l0': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l1': u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'python_l2': u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\User\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe',
 'read_only': False,
 'scripts_dir': 'Scripts',
 'user_data': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Canopy'}
INFO|2013-10-31 12:11:23,451|Running app with args: [u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\System\\Scripts\\pythonw.exe', '-c', 'from canopy.app.main import main; main()']
INFO|2013-10-31 12:11:23,608|Supervising crashes with: ['C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86\\Lib\\site-packages\\canopy\\app\\supervisor.pyc', '--pid', '3340', '--home', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy', '--app', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Enthought\\Canopy32\\App\\Canopy.exe']
INFO|2013-10-31 12:13:00,907|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
INFO|2013-10-31 12:13:01,063|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
DEBUG|2013-10-31 12:13:01,188|Bootstrap already locked by dead process.
INFO|2013-10-31 12:13:01,188|Process that locked layers is dead with info {}
INFO|2013-10-31 12:13:09,523|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 12:13:09,631|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 12:13:43,073|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 12:13:43,198|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 12:17:28,760|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 12:17:28,917|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 12:21:51,957|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 12:21:52,082|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 12:24:49,377|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 12:24:49,517|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 12:25:08,068|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 12:25:08,177|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 12:25:58,301|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 12:25:58,411|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 12:26:44,950|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 12:26:45,059|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 12:27:10,309|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 12:27:10,434|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 12:31:04,530|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 12:31:04,640|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 12:35:18,119|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 12:35:18,244|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 12:36:20,177|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 12:36:20,301|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 12:36:57,769|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 12:36:57,878|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 12:51:00,759|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 12:51:01,029|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 12:51:49,223|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 12:51:49,358|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 14:13:55,292|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 14:13:55,447|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 15:23:13,539|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 15:23:13,663|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 15:23:47,953|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 15:23:48,062|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 15:24:39,559|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 15:24:39,684|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 16:45:52,976|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 16:45:53,101|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
INFO|2013-10-31 16:48:35,884|=============  Start bootstrap logging =================
ERROR|2013-10-31 16:48:35,994|Error performing bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 1024, in main
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 374, in _acquire_lock
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 225, in acquire
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''


===C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Enthought\Canopy32\System\install.log===

INFO|2013-10-30 08:34:55,950|LOCAL-REPO found at: C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86\LOCAL-REPO
INFO|2013-10-30 08:34:56,062|Installing CanopyTrainingCreator-0.5.dev1190-591.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:35:25,046|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:35:25,046|Installing boto-2.6.0-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:35:47,825|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:35:47,825|Installing requests-1.2.3-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:35:55,907|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:35:55,907|Installing addons ...
INFO|2013-10-30 08:35:55,907|Installing CanopyTraining_addon-0.5.591-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:35:56,507|Installing CanopyApp_addon-1.1.0.1371-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:35:57,092|==================================================
INFO|2013-10-30 08:35:57,092|Installing eggs in layer2
INFO|2013-10-30 08:35:57,092|Installing appinst-2.1.2-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:35:58,244|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:35:58,244|Installing casuarius-1.1-2.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:35:59,176|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:35:59,176|Installing cloud-2.4.6-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:36:01,923|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:36:01,923|Installing configobj-4.7.2-2.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:36:06,470|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:36:06,470|Installing distribute-0.6.26-2.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:36:09,421|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:36:09,437|Installing etsproxy-0.1.2-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:37:59,165|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:37:59,165|Installing Examples-7.3-0.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:38:39,161|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:38:39,161|Installing idle-2.7.3-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:38:45,299|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:38:45,299|Installing ipython-0.13.1-2.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:39:15,141|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:39:15,141|Installing Jinja2-2.6-2.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:39:21,684|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:39:21,684|Installing kernmagic-0.2.0-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:39:22,655|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:39:22,655|Installing nose-1.2.1-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:39:27,180|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:39:27,180|Installing numpy-1.7.1-2.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:40:00,717|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:40:00,733|Installing pandas-0.12.0-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:40:28,099|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:40:28,099|Installing PIL-1.1.7-12.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:40:42,144|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:40:42,144|Installing ply-3.4-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:40:42,755|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:40:42,769|Installing pyaudio-0.2.4-3.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:40:43,286|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:40:43,286|Installing pyface-4.3.0-2.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:40:56,157|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:40:56,157|Installing pyglet-1.1.4-2.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:41:01,056|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:41:01,056|Installing Pygments-1.6.0-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:41:14,318|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:41:14,318|Installing pyparsing-1.5.6-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:41:27,296|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:41:27,296|Installing python_dateutil-1.5-2.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:41:31,243|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:41:31,243|Installing PythonDoc-2.7.3-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:41:38,632|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:41:38,632|Installing pytz-2011n-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:41:58,282|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:41:58,282|Installing pyzmq-2.2.0-3.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:42:06,078|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:42:06,078|Installing scipy-0.12.0-2.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:43:01,706|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:43:01,706|Installing sympy-0.7.2-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:43:51,023|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:43:51,023|Installing tornado-2.2-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:43:54,713|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:43:54,713|Installing traits-4.3.0-2.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:44:00,842|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:44:00,842|Installing traitsui-4.3.0-2.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:44:17,384|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:44:17,384|Installing wxPython-2.8.10.1-3.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:45:17,846|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:45:17,846|Installing apptools-4.2.0-2.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:45:33,592|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:45:33,608|Installing enable-4.3.0-6.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:45:46,038|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:45:46,038|Installing enaml-0.6.8-3.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:45:57,951|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:45:57,951|Installing encore-0.3-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:45:59,594|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:45:59,594|Installing envisage-4.3.0-2.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:46:09,038|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:46:09,038|Installing matplotlib-1.3.0-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:46:34,711|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:46:34,711|Installing chaco-4.3.0-2.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:46:46,234|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:46:46,234|Installing pyreadline-1.7.1-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:46:49,315|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:46:49,315|Installing pywin32-214-3.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:47:28,811|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:47:28,811|Installing _registry_path-1.0-1.egg
INFO|2013-10-30 08:47:32,532|Done.
INFO|2013-10-30 08:47:32,532|Completed installation.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469109/enthought-canopy-express-installation-problems-windows-7-x64

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using Enthought Canopy, and sorry for the trouble.

It will probably suffice to log out of Windows, log back in again, then locate the following directory:

```
C:\Users\username\Appdata\Roaming\Enthought\Canopy\
```

and delete, from that directory, all of the following files (if they exist):

```
proc_manager.lock
process.lck
running_procs.pkl
```

Then restart Canopy.

In the next release, this should usually happen automatically in this situation.

For future reference, the easiest way to stop a runaway program is usually to use the "Interrupt Kernel" or (stronger) "Restart Kernel" from the Run menu

Comment: Can I restart the kernel manually?  These files are not available. I reinstalled and placed in a new folder called Canopy.  Same thing! On this computer I also have Python [IDLE].  Could it be playing a role in the non start of the application?

Answer (score 0):

Solved...I removed the IDLE version of Python. Now everything works like clockwork!